# What type of file is a mac cache?

Tags: macos, caching

I saw that discord had a cache on windows, so I went searching for it on mac.  Found it but the file type is unknown to me.  They all seem to have "_0" after them and no ".something"

Comment: There is no single fixed file format for a cache. It’s a [general term](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cache_(computing)) for any local storage that saves the result of some some computationally expensive or time consuming process.

Comment: Regarding the file format used by “discord”, whatever that is, that’s undoubtedly unique to that product and may even vary from one platform to another.